# Error generating abi file for type "double" or "float" using eosiocpp tool

Tags: smart-contract, abi

I am writing a smart contract that uses a multi index table with a member type double.

```
//@abi table tbltest i64
struct test{
    uint64_t uid;
    double margin;

    uuid_t primary_key() const { return uid; }

    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(test,(uid)(margin))
};
```

When I try to generate an abi file using eosiocpp tool I get the following error

```
root@eos# eosiocpp -g test.abi test.cpp
3583446ms thread-0   main.cpp:105                  main                 ] 
999999 abi_generation_exception: Unable to generate abi
false: types can only be: vector, struct, class or a built-in type. (double)
type":"double"}
thread-0  abi_generator.cpp:606 add_type
{}
thread-0  abi_generator.cpp:290 handle_decl
```

If I change the type to uint64_t it works. But It generates an error if I use float or double. 
Why abi-generator does not support these types?

Comment: Maybe you should add the definition of your multi_index table, that we can analyze the cause of the error...
Did you try to use the double as primary key? Documentation says only uint64_t is allowed to be the primary key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue in eosiocpp tool is resolved in the release version 1.0.2 as I am not getting this error now.
I got this error previously in Dawn 4.0.0

Comment: Can you tell me how you update your version to 1.0.2, Am also getting the same error while compiling my abi file.